# How can I change my Visual Studio 2010 Help (F1) from local to online?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration

The first time I pressed F1 in Visual Studio 2010, I mistakenly chose to use local help files (which I don't have) rather than online.

Now, whenever I press F1 in VS2010, The Microsoft Help Viewer 1.1 launches with nothing in it.

**How do I change the F1 behaviour to online help?**

Note: There appear to be Help settings in Tools > Options for [VS2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zzt41xa%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [VS2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zzt41xa%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), but none for [VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kct8y8f0.aspx)?

Answer (score 29):

The help settings are set in Visual Studio 2010's Help Manager:

- Help -> Manage Help Settings
- Choose Online or Local Help.

In Visual Studio 2012, you can find it in:

- Help -> Add and Remove Help Content
- Add or Remove content as you like. Update button on the bottom right.

[image]

Comment: When I do that, I get asked to "Set local content location".  There's a Library location field with a Browse... button, but no option to choose online or local help.

Comment: Set the location, and then you should be able to set local/online.

Comment: I don't have a location (it's not installed) but I'll try changing it to something (anything) and see how I go.

Comment: I have a location set, but I don't have any help stuff installed either.

I just set the location anyway. Once I did that, I got the "Help Library Manager" window, which has a "Choose online or local help" section.

Comment: I can't "Set local content location"! Error '..The location cannot be set by non-administrator user accounts.'

Comment: @Iain Setting where local content is held is a different question (the answer is: use an admin account).

Comment: I want to switch to online help, per the question. Is there no way to get there without an admin account? (locked-down corporate environment)

Comment: @Iain I don't think (can't currently check) you need admin rights to switch your account preference. As admin is need to update local help without admin the local help will be out of date soon. (If your employer doesn't trust locally you how do they trust the code you write?)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, if I click "OK" on the location it gave me it then sat and thought for a bit, then gave me the option to pick.

Options were:

```
choose online or local help
check for updates online
install content from online
install content from disk
remove content.
```

Comment: CONFIRMED - BugFinder's approach worked for me: Help => `Manage Help Settings` => added a random letter to the existing path => pressed `ok` => after a few seconds a dialogue box appeared which included the option to `Choose online or local help` [CONTEXT: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium v10.0.402191 SP1Rel]

Answer (score 3):

With VS2012 choose Help->Set Help Preference->Launch in Browser (or Launch in Help Viewer)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the trailing slash C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\HelpLibrary\  <--  And press OK. Then VS2012 will open new settings window, where you can choose online help/